# Waves currently uses 3M or 3N as prefix for wallet addresses generation, is it posible to change it to AH instead of 3?

Tags: wavesplatform

I'm trying to fork waves. In doing so is it possible to change this ?
I have found this: [Wallet.scala](https://github.com/wavesplatform/Waves/blob/master/node/src/main/scala/com/wavesplatform/wallet/Wallet.scala)

Can somebody please guide me ? I'm new to this.
Thank you!